# What's the best way to implement events to communicate between services and anything else?

Tags: angularjs, events, service

So let's say I have a controler that dppends on a `news` service. Whenever news is published, the controller would like to diisplay the latest news. I'd rather not use `$broadcast` and `$on`, because this does weird things to the way components are coupled. Components which don't depend on `news` could still listen for these events.

So, here's what I'd like to be able to do:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["news", function(news){
    news.onPublish.addListener(function(story){
        ... Show the latest juicy story.
    });
}]);
```

`news.onPublish` would be an Event instance, with `Event` defined as follows:

```
Event = function(){
  var listeners = [];

  this.addListener = function(l){
    listeners.push(l);
  }

  this.trigger = function(){
    var params = arguments
    listeners.map(function(l){
      l.apply(undefined, params);
    });
  }

  return this
}
```

Is this a good way to implement communication between services and other components? Also, would it be good to call `$rootScope.$apply` at the end of `Event.trigger` so that any changes the listeners made will be picked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to write common data storing factories that do the job for you. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9L5xL8sx/ which shows how this works. The `NewsService` factory can be used across several Angular modules, and within the same module, as shown in my example.

Here's the JS:

```
var app = angular.module("TestSharing", []);

app.factory("NewsService", [function() {
    var articles = [];
    var makeNews = function (text) {
        articles.push({text: text});
    };
    var getNews = function() {
        return articles;
    };
    return {
        get: getNews,
        make: makeNews 
    };
}]);

app.controller("FirstCtrl", ["$scope", "NewsService", function($scope, NewsService) {
    $scope.articles = function () {
        return NewsService.get();
    };
}]);

app.controller("SecondCtrl", ["$scope", "NewsService",  function($scope, NewsService) {
    $scope.articletext = "";
    $scope.submit = function () {
        NewsService.make($scope.articletext);
    };
}])
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="TestSharing">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <span ng-repeat="article in articles()">{{article.text}}<br/></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="articletext"/>
        <button ng-click="submit()">Make some news</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, services like these can also share events. For example, if you'd used the factory to expose an object called `somethingNew`, which merely contained if something new had happened in one of the Controllers it had been shared in, you could achieve the same effect. The idea would be to only listen for changes where you'd want (using something like `$scope.$watch(NewsService.somethingNew, function (now, then) {…})`) and that would be just as easy.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this relies on NewsService.get() returning the list of articles by reference, allowing users of the service to modify the array directly.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time, to avoid it do `return angular.copy(<objecttobecopied>)` in the `get` function.

Comment: Doesn't that break binding unless you do $rootScope.$apply when submitting news?

Comment: It should behave the same way, and should be done only if you'd want to restrict access to the array holding the news.